# How to mark certain methods in WCF silverlight enabled service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have WCF silverlight enabled service. I have some methods in it.
I need to mark certain methods in service and
then to determine them when I have get all methods of service by Reflection.

MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(TypeOfTheService).GetMethods();

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for.... you want to put a special attribute on certain methods and then check for the presence of that attribute through reflection?

Comment: @marc_s:  The question I suppose is do attributes that are assigned to methods on the server-side end up being replicated on the silverlight proxy type create for the client-side.  I would guess not but then I know little about WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about don't do that.  Instead create a different contract containing only the  Methods you would otherwise mark.